# fread statement seemingly doing nothing

Tags: c, typedef, fopen, fread

I'm trying to read a file 512 bytes at a time, I have an array set up that contains 512 empty byte-size cells and I currently have an fread set up to read a file into that array, it compiles fine and I dont receive any runtime errors however when I look in the debugger the array is always empty, can anyone see why fread isn't adding the file bytes to my array?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //only accept 1 argument, the target file
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //create FILE object to store input file
    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    //validate input file
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    //declare buffer array of 512 bytes
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];

    //read infile into buffer array
    fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, infile);
}
```

Comment: Code looks mostly ok. Maybe you are not interpreting the debugger results correctly. What do you mean by "the array is always empty"? Can you show your debugging data? One thing to check is the return value of `fread` which will tell you clearly how much it has successfully read. And what contents does the infile have?

Comment: *"I dont receive any runtime errors"* - how do you know that if you are not even checking for them?

Comment: Thanks, the file I was given for this was a .raw with some JPEG's hidden inside. It likely has a few empty 512 byte chunks at the start before the JPEG's begin, if I iterate over a couple more of these chunks I think I'll start to then fill my buffer with JPEG data, thanks for confirming the code was ok though, I think I'd still be trying to find a nonexistent mistake otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the return status from **fread**.
It may be failing.
**errno**, might have the reason.